# uicollectionview cell frame in portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I am stuck in frame of uicollectionview cell frame
what I want to do is,

in landscape mode of iPad I want to show 3 cells,
and in portrait 2 cells.

when I write the code of frame in method `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
its not affecting the size of frame.

I checked by applying debugger whether its coming in this method or not.
but its coming and returning the size.

by default I have to launch my application in landscape and then if required in portrait.

Here is how its showing in landscape

[image]

Here how this cells looking in portrait

[image]

Here is my code for frame

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //return [self.cellSizes[indexPath.item] CGSizeValue];
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
    {
        return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    }
    return CGSizeMake(200, 200);
}
```

What ever value I pass, frame is not at all changing.
I didn't passed any other frame value any where.

I want to give hardcoded value to cell frame first then will go for dynamic.
but I'm stuck at the first place only.
Can any one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: every time it is returning the 200

Comment: No, I don't think so. the frame that I am getting is much bigger than 200. even after removing that line, it gives the same frame

Comment: @stallone Try to Invalidate the CollectionViewLayout when the Orientation delegates get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced similiar problem so basically  you should implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your view controller otherwise design a custom collectionviewcell and register in your view controller , it will definitely work . Try it .

in my case 
i added xib by subclassing  UICollectionViewCell and designed it accordingly and it works so you may try .

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic collection view cell you can use collection view methods like this.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
  return 1;
    }

 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:  (NSInteger)section{
    return [_elements count];
   }

  -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    MosaicCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   MosaicData *data = [_elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.mosaicData = data;

    float randomWhite = (arc4random() % 40 + 10) / 255.0;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:randomWhite alpha:1];
     return cell;
   }
```

For details you can see this example. This is an perfect example of your need
https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout

Comment: Rick, thanks for comment. but using arc4random changes my cell frame very time I launch the application, i already tried it. i need to set hardcoded value for frame in such way that, in portrait mode iPad will show 2 cells column and in landscape mode it will show 3 cells column

Comment: @stallone then you can use hard code values in place of dynamic(arc4random)
or
You can make custom collectionView cell

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the collection view when orientation will get change. so the CGRect size method will be called for the cell to recreate cell.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    // do something after rotation
    [_collectView reloadData];
}
```

Add this method and reload your collection view so  `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`   will get called and size will get changed.
Thanks